# Dynamically populated javascript slideshow

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to create a dynamically populated javascript slide show for an e-commerce site, where I have a product list with several categories.

I would like to be able to create slide shows with roughly 5 linked images displaying at one time, starting with newest products. I'd like to be able to take them all from the same list and put them in different slide shows, so for images from category 1 they are in category 1 slide show, same for cat 2,3, etc...

Is there a tutorial or series of tutorials that could teach me this that someone would personally recommend (there is plenty on dynamically populated javascript and plenty on slide shows, but nothing that links the two in a way I can understand).

If there isn't would someone be willing to share a sample code or something for it, if I can see the code I can figure it out for myself, but if you are willing to explain in detail then that would be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you might need to hire or befriend someone who's paid/willing to help you figure your problem out. Not sure SO is the right place to ask for an "answer" to this kind of question.

Comment: hiring someone to do it won't teach me how to do it really... but thanks for the suggestion and the edit.

Comment: Hence the second option in my comment. SO is not a tutorial site, unfortunately.

Comment: Not of any use to anyone else. Try a chatroom.

Comment: So SO is just for helping debug and fix problems, not for learning? Don't get me wrong, I'm not questioning you on whether this is a tutorial site, hence why I was asking to be redirected to a tutorial that would explain it if it was too much to be explained here, but if this is too... deep (i guess you could say) then it would help to know what the limits to a question are, or what makes the difference between a reasonable "help me figure this out" question and a "i need a tutorial" question, I've asked a question or two in the past and got similar responses so I guess I need guidance on that

Comment: Tomalak, it would be useful to me, and I'm sure it would be useful to loads of people who can't figure out how to dynamically populate their js. Your response benefited who exactly?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can try this tutorial: http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/

Comment: That's very similar except i was hoping for a row of images on each "slide" that is constant cycling itself, and i dont think it is actually dynamically populating. The thing is that this site is going to have users submitting their products, so it would need to auto update itself i guess you could say, so if someone loads something at 2 am, and someone comes on the site at 2:01 they see the first image in the slideshow would be the most recent upload. Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: @Nathan - You would need to load your list in the browser dynamically then, i.e., AJAX.

Comment: Jared, that makes loads of sense now, that helped my search anyways, so just to make sure I understand right, AJAX is more focused on the communication aspects of the slideshow, where jquery just simplifies and cleans up the visual aspects?

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library. you can also use it to do an AJAX "protocol".  ajax also referencing to a method of contacting the server from the client using Javascript.  you may need to take a look at tutorials in javascript, jquery and ajax. this will give you a better idea than jump start in slideshows.